# analytics:reportChart in VisualForce Salesforce

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, salesforce, visualforce

I use the analytics:reportChart functionality to display a graph in the page layout. I was wondering if it's possible to overwrite what happens when users click on the graph? Right now a new Salesforce-window with tabs and header opens on the page of the record I'm already on. Is it a way to hide the header and tabs in this window or to open the filtered report in a new window? I tried to add filters to a custom link, but it doesn't seem to work.

And another question: is it possible to overwrite the fact that Salesforce truncates record names on the x-axis? I have a lot of accounts that starts with the same name, so the graph is really confusing right now.

This is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="dashBoardController">

<a href="/00O11000000T0tc?pc0={!Id}&pn0=eq&pv0={!left(Account.Id,15)}" target="_blank">Link to the report </a>

<analytics:reportChart reportId="00O11000000T0tc" hideonerror="true"
 filter="{column:'Account.Kunde_avtaleniv_skjul__c', operator:'equals',value:'{!left(Account.Id,15)}'}"
 size="small"> 
</analytics:reportChart>

</apex:page>
```